# Shapeless error: not found: value Second

Tags: scala, shapeless

I have following a project that contains following code:

```
package ch.khinkali

import shapeless.{::, HList, HNil}


trait Second[L <: HList] {
  type Out

  def apply(value: L): Out
}

object Second {
  type Aux[L <: HList, O] = Second[L] {type Out = O}

  def apply[L <: HList](implicit inst: Second[L]): Aux[L, inst.Out] =
    inst
}


object Main {

  implicit def hlistSecond[A, B, Rest <: HList]: Second.Aux[A :: B :: Rest, B] =
    new Second[A :: B :: Rest] {
      type Out = B

      def apply(value: A :: B :: Rest): B =
        value.tail.head
    }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val second1 = Second[String :: Boolean :: Int :: HNil]
    println(second1)
  }

}
```

When I try on the `Shell` following:

```
 val second1 = Second[String :: Boolean :: Int :: HNil]
```

it shows the error message:

```
 error: not found: value Second
```

I do import the package, as you can see the picture below:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try wildcard imports:

```
import ch.khinkali._
import shapeless._
import ch.khinkali.Main._
```

Comment: I've got further error `error: wrong number of type arguments for ::, should be 1`

Comment: @zero_coding Updated.

Comment: And futher error again `error: could not find implicit value for parameter inst: ch.khinkali.Second[String :: Boolean :: Int :: shapeless.HNil]`,   although I do have instance for it, as you can see the code above.

Comment: @zero_coding Updated.